# how to decrypt AES CBC 256 : while you have the Key and the IV

Tags: aes, cbc

I've been working on a forensics challenge , and I'm in the last step , i have an AES CBC 256 encrypted string and i need to decrypt it .. is there's and well known tool , or a script of some kind 'python' or 'C' ?

and if there's other resources to learn about this specefic type of encryption

note : i find a python script for the AES but it doesn't include the CBC "IV"

this is what im trying to decrypt ..

> KEY = 7869686966766E6C6F697570756E707100000000000000000000000000000000
>
> IV = 6C7579796E6171726E7371627368616C
>
> Encrypted data: N3xlOTgnywpPupc1VXbP9FbOXb1pK+S+CzQOo4KtqGz/hVMQ6ki6rNoBkKik733j

Comment: You can use [PyCrypto](https://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/) as follows: `plaintext = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv).decrypt(ciphertext)`.

Comment: Have you tried looking on google? http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc/index is the fourth link down and I didn't even include CBC in my search terms.

Comment: i did but its not giving anything meaningful

Comment: �vSL��V%��Yȓ�PLo��ܩ�ƅL����_�YO����Ho�T_�&